# CakePHP model assosciation: View product image

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a products model, and each product has several images. So `Product`-`hasMany`-`Image`.

Now when I browse some product I am able to see the images that it has but not able to view the images when I list the products in the index.
How should I get the first image from the product to display it in the index?

The only way I can manage to deal with this is to use the `Image` model inside the `Products`controller but I guess that this is not the best option.

EDIT:
Most of the stuff is just like after baked. By default does the hasMany display when listing all the products?

Model:

```
class Product extends AppModel {
var $hasMany = array(
    'Image' => array(
        'className' => 'Image',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
        'dependent'=> false
    ),
);    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some examples of the code you are using?

Comment: if it's freshly baked this functionality already exists - even with `recursive=0` cake should return Product and it's associated images. As you can view the images when viewing a product, you should post the index method of `products`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have used the bake script, your index action will most likely have this line in it:

```
$this->Product->recursive = 0;
```

This will disable all the relations that you've set. Comment/remove this line and you should be able to display the image properly (it should be under $this->data['Product']['Image']).

Comment: ok, i think that this was the problem and I dont know why by default this line exists. Thanks!

Comment: This line exists by default, because the bake script assumes it's creating an index table for just the given model. But many times you'll want to display data from related models as well, so this line should be removed.